# How to change color of a div with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why when I click on the div that have the class round the color don't change?
   Also, how can I make it to change `onclick` ?

```js
var round = document.querySelector(".round");
round.addEventListener("click", function() {
  round.style.backroundColor = "blue";
});
```

```css
.round {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
```

Comment: You have a typo `backroundColor` should be `backgroundColor`

Comment: Try `querySelectorAll` with a loop. `querySelector()` returns the first element within the document that matches the specified selector

Answer (score 1):

The first reason is that you didn't spell `backgroundColor` correctly.

But, even with that fixed, only the first circle would work because you used `querySelector()`, which stops looking for matches after the first match and returns only that one match.

You could use `querySelectorAll()`, which finds all the matching elements and returns them as a node list. But then you would have to loop over the node list and attach event handlers on each node. This certainly will work, but a better approach would be to leverage [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) and listen for `click` at a higher level.

Also, instead of creating inline styles (which are difficult to override later), it's better to use pre-existing CSS classes and apply or remove them as needed with [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Below, I'm showing how to toggle color on/off on successive clicks.

```js
// Listen for clicks at a higher level that click will bubble up to
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Check to see if a "round" element was the trigger for the event
  if(event.target.classList.contains("round")){
    // Style the trigger based on adding/removing the pre-existing class
    event.target.classList.toggle("highlight")  
  }
});
```

```css
.round {
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
   background-color: #bbb;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 
 /* This will be applied or removed as needed */
 .highlight {
   background-color:blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector()` selects only the first matching element, you need `querySelectorAll()` which returns a `NodeList`.

Since not all browsers support `forEach()` on NodeList objects, you cast the `NodeList` to an `Array` using array destructuring, then iterate over it using `forEach()` and add the event listeners:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".round")].forEach((round) => {
  round.addEventListener("click", function() {
    round.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  })
})
```

```css
.round {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
```

Comment: forEach is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @codeWithMe Guess why I did `[...document.querySelectorAll(".round")]` and explicitly explained what you commented.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you should use `querySelectorAll()` to select all element instances that match the `.round` selector.

The `querySelectorAll()` method returns a collection of matching elements which you can iterate through and then add click events per element to perform the style/background color update:

```js
// Use querySelectorAll to select all instances of 'round'
// as a collection
var rounds = document.querySelectorAll(".round");

// Iterate each element
for(const round of rounds) {

  // Attach click event to each element instance
  round.addEventListener("click",function(event){
     
    // Use element from event, fix typo "backgroundColor"
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor ="blue";  
  });
}
```

```css
.round {
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
   background-color: #bbb;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` and fix your typo with backgroundColor

```
let round = document.querySelectorAll('.round');
for (let element of round) {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  })
}
```

Comment: `forEach()` is not supported in all browsers on node lists.

Comment: Thanks. So better use a for loop then.

Comment: Just convert the node list to an array and then you can use the full Array API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the approach below. See my comments too:

```js
//Use querySelectorAll to return a NodeList of all items matching the query
var rounds = document.querySelectorAll(".round");

//Iterate over each item
Array.prototype.forEach.call(rounds, function(round) {
  //Add an event listener
  round.addEventListener('click', onRoundClick("blue"));
});

function onRoundClick(color) {
  //Return a handler that changes the bg color of calling object
  return function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

```css
.round {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
<div class="round"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var round = document.querySelectorAll('.round');
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0;i < round.length;i++) {
    round[i].style.backgroundColor="blue";
  };
};
```

You did not spell 'background' correctly.

Comment: i want to use only the for loop but this make them all turn to blue and i want that only the one that i click on will turn blue

Comment: Oh, well in that case...